# MySQL Query select issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this current MySQL Query in my PHP script:

```
SELECT WEEK(date),COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE team='1' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY WEEK(date) 
ORDER BY MONTH(date) ASC
```

This creates an json array like this: `[["36","154"],["37","247"],["38","266"]]` where 36, 37, 38 is the week number, and 154, 247, 266 is number of rows in table.

But what if I want to include team 2 also, so team 1 and 2?

I tried changing like the one below, but I get no value:

```
SELECT WEEK(date),COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE team='1' AND team='2' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY WEEK(date) 
ORDER BY MONTH(date) ASC;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me out please?

EDIT: This is how it looks like:

```
| ID |         date        | TEAM |
|  1 | 2020-09-22 17:31:32 |   1  |
|  2 | 2020-09-22 15:14:43 |   1  |
|  3 | 2020-09-17 16:23:54 |   2  |
|  4 | 2020-09-17 11:23:11 |   1  |
|  5 | 2020-09-15 15:32:26 |   2  |
```

The expected result should be an array instead of this: `[["36","154"],["37","247"],["38","266"]]` I also want to include team 2, like this: `[["36","154","144"],["37","247","233"],["38","266","286"]]` where the last string is number or rows for team 2

Comment: team cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time, it can be either 1 or 2...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh phpMyAdmin

Comment: You probably mean MySQL.

Comment: When GROUP BY, you can only ORDER BY select list items.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, MySQL, sorry.

Comment: No problem. (Just to make sure you get answer that runs on your dbms.)

Comment: @jarlh Edited my question to add dataset now if that makes it more clear :)

Comment: Great. But we want both sample table data _and_ the expected result! [mcve]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @jarlh Sorry I am new. The expected result should be an array instead of this: `[["36","154"],["37","247"],["38","266"]]` I also want to include team 2, like this: `[["36","154","144"],["37","247","233"],["38","266","286"]]` where the last string is number or rows for team 2.

Comment: No problem. But don't give it as a comment, edit the question instead.

Comment: @jarlh Done. Are you able to help with my issue also please?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for rows that its `team` value is `'1'` AND `'2'` simultaneously, which is not possible. That's why you get empty result.

Comment: So how do I need to call it?

Comment: What do you like your result to be? I didn't understand what you meant by "include team 2 also". Do you want to simply OR between them? Do you want to group them?

Comment: I want to group them. To also include the number of rows for team 2 in the array. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what your dataset looks like, but try querying data where team is 1 OR 2.

```
SELECT WEEK(date),COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE (team='1' OR team='2') AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY WEEK(date) 
ORDER BY MONTH(date) ASC;
```